# SQL Server : extracting number from a string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to following SQL command to extract only numbers from a string :

```
UPDATE Oesskattings 
SET alfasorteer1 = CASE 
                      WHEN CHARINDEX('-', blokno) > 0 
                         THEN SUBSTRING(blokno + '-', 0, CHARINDEX('-', blokno))
                      ELSE SUBSTRING(blokno, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', blokno), LEN(blokno)) 
                   END
```

My problem is when I have a record where blokno is eg 1B (conversion failed where number is followed by character).

How can I improve my code?

Regards

Comment: Please update your question to include some sample data.

Comment: What number does 1B represent? If you just want to ignore it use a `where` caluse like this: `where blokno not like '%[A-Z]'%`

Comment: "1B" is clearly a hexadecimal value equal to XXXVII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will pull out all numbers from a string regardless of other characters and sequence.

It uses a Recursive CTE to identify numbers in order, then puts them back together with STUFF XML PATH

```
DROP TABLE #TMP
CREATE TABLE #TMP(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),txt VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES
('q12w--e32w')
,('vfr45tgbnhy67')
,('12wq3&&r5f5')
,('1qw%%23er45t')
,('de32()ws2')
,('desfghj')

;WITH A
    AS (
    SELECT ID,1 POS
            ,txt
            ,SUBSTRING(txt,PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',txt),1) CHR
            ,RIGHT(txt,LEN(txt)-PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',txt)) REM
    FROM #TMP
    WHERE PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',txt) > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID,POS + 1 
            ,txt
            ,SUBSTRING(REM,PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',REM),1) CHR
            ,RIGHT(REM,LEN(REM)-PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',REM)) REM
    FROM
        A
    WHERE
        PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',REM) > 0
    )
,c AS
    (
SELECT 
    ID,txt
    ,STUFF(
        (SELECT ''+b.chr
        FROM a b
        WHERE a.ID = b.id
        ORDER BY POS
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'') AS chrs
FROM 
    A
    )
SELECT DISTINCT 
    *
FROM
    C
```

Comment: Thank you pacreely.

Comment: @Gideon: Did the code work for you? I had to make a big guess on what your source data might be like.

Comment: How can I order the numbers of chrs column DESC (seems to be wrong type I guess)?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to delete all non-numeric characters in the string with :

```
    set alfasorteer1 = substring(blokno, patindex('%[0-9]%', blokno),    1+patindex('%[0-9][^0-9]%', blokno+'x')-patindex('%[0-9]%', blokno))
```